# What is the difference between putAll(Map map) and accumulateAll(Map map) method of json-lib?

Tags: java, json, json-lib

**`JsonObjectclass`** of Library **`json-lib-2.2.3(net.sf.json)`** has two methods :

```
public void putAll( Map map )
```

***AND***

```
public void accumulateAll( Map map )
```

I have to put all map details in JSONObject.

***Which method should i use and why(i.e What is the difference between the two) ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/) on `accumulate`:

> Accumulate values under a key. It is similar to the element method except that if there is already an object stored under the key then a JSONArray is stored under the key to hold all of the accumulated values. If there is already a JSONArray, then the new value is appended to it. In contrast, the replace method replaces the previous value.

From this, it seems that `accumulateAll` would call `accumulate` for all values in the map, i.e. values already in the object are not replaced, whereas `putAll` might replace existing values.

Example:

You have an object like this: `{"chars":"A"}`.

- `putAll` with a map containing `"chars" -> "B"` would result in `{"chars":"B"}`
- `accumulateAll` with a map containing `"chars" -> "B"` would result in `{"chars":["A","B"]}`